# How do you start a background task on device/application startup for windows WinRT/c#

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova, windows-runtime, winjs

How can I start a background task that implements `IBackgroundTask` in a universal app for windows/windows phone?

I am using cordova to create an app for ios, android, wp8 and windows.  Each platform seems to run a native class before the application starts, so you can add code here to start a task/service.  When a windows project is created by cordova, it is created as a javascript project so there is no c# file to start with.

Is my only option to add `winJs` code to start the background task?

Comment: hi, have you ever figured this out? would you mind sharing the knowledge as I'm in a similar scenario. I've created the native app, with background task, but would like to switch to Cordova app but not sure how would I now register the background task.. samples would be helpful. thanks

Comment: Hi, yeah i figured out in the end.  I created it as a cordova plugin, and then wrote the code to start the background service using winJs, which is called via the WindowsProxy.js file that cordova calls.

Comment: answered question in full for you, see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, i got round this by creating it as a cordova plugin.  So my plugin has a method called init, which i call when the app starts up.  Using the plugin, i can call services in iOS, Android or Windows.

Once i created the plugin, i then started my windows service from within the WindowProxy.js file, which is part of the cordova plugin.

Note, that your service itself must be in a separate Library, and that library must have the output type set as Windows Runtime Component.

Sample code to start the service is as follows

Code in WindowsProxy.js file

```
init: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {

        var taskRegistered = false;
        var taskName = "Your Background Task Name";
        var background = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
        var iter = background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.allTasks.first();

        // check if service already started
        while (iter.hasCurrent) {
            var task = iter.current.value;

            if (task.name === taskName) {
                taskRegistered = true;
                break;
            }

            iter.moveNext();
        }

        if (taskRegistered) {
            successCallback();
        } else {
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.requestAccessAsync().then(function () {
                var builder = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();

                builder.name = taskName;
                builder.taskEntryPoint = "CordovaApp.Library.UploadTask"; // namespace of my windows runtime component library
                builder.setTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger(15, false));
                builder.addCondition(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemCondition(Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemConditionType.internetAvailable));

                return builder.register();
            }).done(function () {
                successCallback();
            }, function (err) {
                errorCallback(err);
            });
        }

    },
```

Comment: thank you. I reckon it shouldn't be a problem for the background service to be a javascript one as I assume in your solution you have it as a C# solution or am I mistaken? cheers

Comment: Mine is in c#. Not sure the background service can be javascript though as it needs to implement the I background task interface (think it's called that but not at pc atm)

Comment: my proof of concept was based on the background task implemented as a javascript file an it worked fine, there is quite a lot of doco on that topic as well. thanks

Comment: Is this enough to start the service? I am testing it and I can not get Run method called. I waited for 15 minutes as well, no luck. I am having exact same problem like you were having.

Comment: Yep this works, i have it running now. Make sure you have the correct names being loaded and also the project types are correct

Comment: @user2736022 windows8.1 and above use javascript not c# and c++

Answer (score 0):

If you need to choose the class to implement...i suggest to write the application natively.

If you want to mantain the core of the logic written in javascript and use this class for a single task that you need to run in background you can write the functionality in native languange for windows, and then follow this [guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html) to wrap it in a cordova plugin.

Personally i suggest this solution, write cordova plugin is pretty simple and very usefull.

Comment: class that implements IBackgroundTask is in native c# language.  I also have the class in another project which is set as a Windows Component Runtime project.  This is so easy in android and ios, you just configure the service to run, and native code runs at startup.  But when you create a windows project with cordova, it creates javascript projects, so you cannot attach native c# code to start the service.

Comment: You can find a lot of example of cordova plugin written in c#, try to check out someone of these: [Barcode](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/master/src/windows8) This one for example use native c# languange to work with a native C library that work on camera stream to check a barcode match. Javascript talk directly with the WinRT component. Use this one or a simplest plugin as reference and wirte yours!

Comment: I know how to call a cordova plugin and create the proxy code for it to run on windows.  That is not the issue.  The issue is trying to run a IBackgroundTask and getting it too run.  Seems silly to run a cordova plugin function to start the service for windows only, since all other platforms would never run the code...

Comment: As mentioned in my answer...if you need to use a IBackgroundTask you can write the app natively, if you want to write a cordovapp, you must use or a js equivalent for manage the background task or write the plugin natively for every platform that you want to use ( obviously if is only once...is silly write a cordova app ).
If the problem is only releated to how implement this class in a winjs application...i think that cordova tag is unnecessary and you must add WinRT, and c# tag, finally can be usefull to edit your question, in this way another user can understand it better and help you.